# How to open PDF in browser onClick of React Button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, web

I want to implement a simple button that will open my resume.pdf file in the browser for the user to view and download. How can I achieve this in react?

`<button className="a-resume" onClick={handleClick()}>resume</button>`

Answer (score 2):

This will open the PDF in a new tab:

```
function handleClick()
{
     window.open("example.com/path/to/resume.pdf","_blank");
}
```

Comment: will my resume.pdf be in the src folder?

Comment: Does the resume.pdf already exist on some server, or is the user uploading it right then?

Comment: mm it does not exist on a server. Is it possible for me to upload it onto my src file for it to be accessed?

Comment: Yes, you can upload the file, but that whole process is beyond the scope of just the React frontend. You will need to create the proper server-side provisions for saving files. There are countless ways to save files on the backend, so research what works best for you.

Comment: You need to have the resume.pdf file available somewhere in the web, and the link inside window.open() must lead there. Be it on the same server from where your frontend files are served, or from somewhere else.

Comment: I see. Thanks so much guys. So in the first argument of "window.open(...)", i will paste a link to where my pdf is?

Comment: Yes, but you should include the `https://` on the URL: `window.open("https://example.com/path/to/resume.pdf","_blank");`

Answer (score 0):

I am answering late but may be useful for others. The following code chunk worked for me-

```js
import {Linking} from "react-native";

//other required code
onPress={() => Linking.openURL('https://example.com/path/to/resume.pdf","_blank')}>
```